# Como criar uma tabela temporária dentro de uma Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, stored-procedures, tabela-temporária

saudações!
Minha dúvida é a seguinte: Gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma tabela temporária dentro de um procedimento, no qual os valores dessa minha tabela temporária serão retirados de uma tabela permanente do meu banco de dados. Da tabela permanente eu só precisarei usar duas colunas para validar meu procedimento.
E após a execução do procedimento excluir essa tabela temporária.

Comment: *"como faço para criar uma tabela temporária dentro de um procedimento"*  usando o comando `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`, como se fosse uma tabela comum

Comment: Mas como chamo para dentro das colunas que estarão na tabela temporária os dados das outras duas colunas da tabela permanente?

Comment: sua pergunta está confusa, o problema é criar a tabela ou inserir dados? para inserir use `INSERT INTO` com select na outra tabela, ou mais fácil `SELECT INTO`

Comment: O problema maior é inserir esses dados vindos de uma outra tabela.